# Generating Mustache Template With Asset Images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mustache

I'm generating a Mustache template within a controller of my rails application. I am able to generate the html just fine. My problem is that I am not able to load in images from the assets folder.

I've tried using `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag` and `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path` and then passing that in as a variable into an image tag in the Mustache template as `<img src="{{ asset_path }}" />` for the asset path and the output of the `image_tag` as it is `<div> {{ image_tag }} </div>`

I know that image_tag and asset_path are picking up the image because when I put in an incorrect path it outputs an error.

Anybody have any ideas on how to link this image to the Mustache template?

Comment: can you please share how you are creating template in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The error was not related to Mustache but to the next phase of the application which is to generate a PDF from the generated HTML.

For reference, I used `Rails.root.join('app','assets','..path to image')` for the image path.